# Django filter from multiple models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I get a list (QuerySet) of objects from which I would like to filter like that:

```py
books = Book.objects.filter(author="Someone")
Paragraph.objects.filter(book=books)
```

I expect to get a QuerySet of paragraphs that are related to the books I got earlier, the problem is that the QuerySet of paragraphs come only from the first book in the QuerySet

Comment: The above should actually error, unless there is only *one* book, so I think something here is wrong with your first query (well there is only one book that matches).

Comment: So what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Well it looks like in your database, you have only one book of `'Someone'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.filter(book__in=books)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In one query: `Paragraph.objects.filter(book__author='Someone')`